# How do I re-write this python code to work within a pyinstaller generated exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

PyInstaller 3.4
Python 3.7
Win 7-64 bit

I made a `.exe` from python code using `PyInstaller` that has the following logic. The goal is to launch the http server in a new console window on Windows. This is to avoid locking up/blocking the main application and the user can just close the newly launched console window when they are finished with the http server.

```
p = subprocess.call('start "" python  -m http.server --directory {} {} --bind {}'.format(web_server_path, web_server_port, web_bind_ip), shell=True)
```

This works on my windows PC that has Python installed but naturally does not work on a PC without Python.

Since the goal is to distribute this `.exe` to people without a python installation, can someone recommend the correct method to accomplish the above behavior using Python within PyInstaller?  I know that a PyInstaller generated `.exe` is essentially running a Python interpreter but I don't know how to tap into it with my code.

***UPDATE***
It is a requirement that the user be able to set the `directory`, `port`, and `address`. It should also be easy to stop ideally by just closing a window (hence the original command line method) but that is open to change.

***FURTHER  UPDATE***
Is it possible to load the python3.dll and use its function directly somehow?
`ctypes.WinDLL('Path:\to\my.dll')`

Comment: The best idea wkuld be to start the HTTP server in code, not via the command line.

Comment: You could create a function that just import `http.server` directly and invoke the `test` function inside it with the appropriate arguments (view the source code for details) and then invoke that function through the `multiprocessing` module to have it be running in a separate process.

Comment: What's the value of `sys.executable`?

Comment: `sys.executable` is the path to my .exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example code would presumably start the web server without blocking the further execution of your script, you'd want to run the web server on a separate thread.

```
from sys import version_info
import http.server
import socketserver
from threading import Thread


class WebServer(Thread):
    @staticmethod
    def get_directory_simple_http_request_handler(directory):
        _current_only = version_info < (3, 7)

        class _DirectorySimpleHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
            _current_only = version_info < (3, 7)

            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                if not self._current_only:
                    kwargs['directory'] = directory
                super(_DirectorySimpleHTTPRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            @property
            def current_only(self):
                return self._current_only

        return _DirectorySimpleHTTPRequestHandler

    def __init__(self, address='127.0.0.1', port=8000, directory=''):
        self.handler = self.get_directory_simple_http_request_handler(directory)
        self.httpd = socketserver.TCPServer((address, port), self.handler)
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.httpd.serve_forever()

    def join(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.httpd.shutdown()
        super().join(*args, **kwargs)


web_server = None
while True:
    if web_server is None:
        print('Currently not running (type start or exit).')
    else:
        print('Running on:', web_server.httpd.server_address, '(type stop or exit)')
        if web_server.handler.current_only:
            print('Serving current directory, Python <3.7 has no `directory` on SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.')

    command = input('>')

    if command == 'start':
        if web_server is None:
            web_server = WebServer(directory=r'C:\Temp')
            web_server.start()
    if command == 'stop':
        if web_server is not None:
            web_server.join()
            web_server = None
    if command == 'exit':
        exit(0)
```

Note that Python 3.7 is the first version to support the `directory` parameter, earlier versions of Python will only serve the current directory for the process.

The factory static method is there to set up a separate instance of the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` which gets initialised with the desired directory.

If you prefer to actually just launch a console window, running the Python (test) web server (or another external server, if Python is not available):

```
import time
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

proc = Popen(['python', '-m', 'http.server', '8000'],
             cwd=r'C:\temp',
             creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, close_fds=True)

while True:
    print('Running')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Similarly, if you like it quiet, but don't need access to the web server object, this also works:

```
import time
from subprocess import Popen

proc = Popen(['python', '-m', 'http.server', '8000'], close_fds=True, cwd=r'C:\temp')

while True:
    print('Running')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code @Grismar. However, this doesn't launch in a new window and therefore, the user doesn't have an easy way to stop it. I'd have to implement some further UI element to do so right? I also have to be able to set the `directory`, `port` and `address`.

Comment: It does not launch in a separate window, which I didn't realise was a feature you actually preferred - you don't have any control over that window once it is launched. I will update the code above to include control over the directory - as you can tell from the code, it already allows you to set port and address.

Comment: You're probably right about not launching in a new window. Since this is in a new thread, it will work well enough. I was trying to avoid threading by launching in a new window with my code. With threading, I no longer have to do that. I can  just add a `stop server' UI element to accomplish that.

Comment: As for the separate window, does this also mean you want the server to continue running, even when your script terminates? Because that's really the only strong reason I would go with a separate process - otherwise, either running it on a thread like this, or going the route of `subprocess.Popen` would be the way to go.

Comment: I've added solutions that either open a window, or quietly launch a process without control, please accept the answer if any of the solutions suits your needs, @frakman1

Comment: Unfortunately @Grismar, both the `Popen()` proposals won't work because the target machine won't have Python installed. That was the whole point behind my posted code. I was wondering if there is a way to do some kind of Popen but use the bundled python in Pyinstaller's exe instead of the system installed python which won't exist on another PC. Does that make sense?

Comment: I tried the above main code. Although the server starts with no issue. When I open a browser to it, I get this error `super(_DirectorySimpleHTTPRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, directory=directory)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'directory'`

Comment: That's strange - I just tried re-running the exact code as above and it runs without issue on Python 3.7 with no additional packages installed. What version of Python are you using? Are you running the exact same code, or did you make minor changes?

Note that the `super` of `_DirectorySimpleHTTPRequestHandler` is `http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` and it does have a `directory` parameter https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because it works when I run the code by itself, but not when I integrate with my code. Anyway, I can't really use this code because there is no way to stop the server. serve_forever() doesn't return.  I need a reliable way to start and stop it multiple times as needed. I can't just Ctrl+C out of the app to stop it.

Comment: You're moving the goalposts here, since you originally wanted something running in a separate window (for which I included example code), which you would not be able to stop either. I can't help with your integration problems, but you *can* stop the server, by simply shutting down the server `web_server.httpd.shutdown()`. You can restart it by calling `run()` on it again. I would suggest carefully reading the example code and understanding why it works and you should have no trouble integrating it - feel free to ask further questions if you have trouble understanding how or why it works.

Comment: I take back what I said about the above code working. It runs at first but when I try to connect to it via a browser, I get the same exact error message. I am using Python 3.6.4 on Win 7 64bit.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies on the Popen bit - I see what you mean, although you could use the exact same solution to run any other small webserver you could include. For example, you could build a Python-based simple webserver based on http.server, turn that into a separate exe and run that, if that solution appeals to you. But running the class from within your application and having control seems far preferable. I was able to reproduce the error using Python 3.6, the ability to provide a different directory was new in 3.7. I'll include a remark to that effect in the answer and add a check to code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185454/discussion-between-grismar-and-frakman1).